Getting a 500 error after trying to use Dexie Cloud
After following the getting started guide on Dexie and Dexie Cloud I'm getting
POST https://[myDbId].dexie.cloud/sync 500 (Internal Server Error)

Followed by a 500 error originating from the dexie-cloud-addon.
hook.js:608 HttpError: 500 
    at dexie-cloud-addon.js?v=5ad80b9f:6120:13
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (dexie-cloud-addon.js?v=5ad80b9f:2841:24)
    at chunk-REMEN4KG.js?v=5ad80b9f:1087:23
    at callListener (chunk-REMEN4KG.js?v=5ad80b9f:858:16)
    at endMicroTickScope (chunk-REMEN4KG.js?v=5ad80b9f:891:23)
    at chunk-REMEN4KG.js?v=5ad80b9f:873:36
    at usePSD (chunk-REMEN4KG.js?v=5ad80b9f:1075:18)
    at physicalTick (chunk-REMEN4KG.js?v=5ad80b9f:872:9)

When I am trying to add a friend with the code from the example, I am getting the following error:
Failed to add dan: DataError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value. DataError: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value.

For data to sync to Dexie Cloud without error. Maybe for an authentication modal to pop up? I'm not ac

500 Internal Server typically indicates an issue on the server side, but it could also result from a misconfiguration in your client application. Look at the detailed response for the POST https://[myDbId].dexie.cloud/sync request in your browser's developer tools. The server response may provide hints about the issue.

The 500 error seem to be related to a recent upgrade (https://github.com/dexie/Dexie.js/issues/2110). A fix is on the way.

The server has now been updated with a fix. To reset your local state before retrying, please go to devtools --> Application --> IndexedDB and delete the database to get a fresh client.
